# I want to create a combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

I want to create a combobox with some style. I dont want old dropdown what we are getting. I want some new dropdown which looks very nice. Is there any way to create a dropdown like that.
Plz give me suggestions

Comment: You really need to do at least a *little* of the work on your own.  This is not a "do my work for me" site.

Comment: Don't be hard on the guy.  He's asking for some suggestions, not a finished product.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this link out on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx)  This is the actual control template for the combo box.  You can copy and paste this into your application (within your [app's Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624.aspx)).

Create a form and slap a combo box on it with some data in it.  Then start changing the control template and view the results.  Start off simply by changing colors and adding borders around elements to see what controls which part.  Then you can start switching out larger parts of the template to match what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

one can start with the standard combobox, and then use various controls and styles to change the look and feel of the control, and it's corresponding drop down.